# how to set the input of spark/hadoop task as a range of files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have a log system, the logs are named by there timestamp.

For example:

```
logs/2015/05/08/21
logs/2015/05/08/22
logs/2015/05/08/23
logs/2015/05/09/00
logs/2015/05/09/01
logs/2015/05/09/02
logs/2015/05/09/04
logs/2015/05/09/05
```

Now I need to select a range of directories as my task's input.

For example(pay attention to that the 05/09/03 is missing. This is normal)

```
logs/2015/05/08/22
logs/2015/05/08/23
logs/2015/05/09/00
logs/2015/05/09/01
logs/2015/05/09/02
logs/2015/05/09/04
```

How to set the file input path? I know it is easy to get the file range from 08/22 to 09/04, but how do I know which file is missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "file input path"? Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 1):

SparckContext.textFile() will take both file system globs and comma-separated paths. So, you could either do:

```
val logLines = sc.textFile("logs/*/*/*/*")
```

Or you could do:

```
val logLines = sc.textFile("logs/2015/05/08/22,logs/2015/05/08/23,logs/2015/05/09/00,logs/2015/05/09/01,logs/2015/05/09/02,logs/2015/05/09/04"
```